# CSS3 - overflow:hidden fixes the height?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a UL with some items in it:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><img alt="FaceBook" src="images/facebook.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img alt="Twitter" src="images/twitter.png" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

It appears on the webpage fine, but the true height of the UL is 0 pixels.

[image]

ONLY when I add `overflow:hidden` parameter to the UL, the height fixes:

[image]

I always thought that `overflow:hidden` only prevents items from going outside of the containter, but do not actually affect the containter's dimentions. While the default height should automatically be high enough to fit in all the items.

***Question:*** Why doesn't the UL have the `auto` height by default, and why does `overflow:hidden` affect it?

Comment: can you put your <li> and <a> styles too. I think they are causing this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `<ul>` takes up as much space as its child elements (see http://jsfiddle.net/). If you are experiencing something other than that you have applied some CSS to it that breaks the default behaviour.

If you `float` your `<li>` tags they would not take up any space anymore, which makes your `<ul>` "disappear". It is still true that it takes up as much space as its children, but now the children don't take up any space anymore since they are floated. Setting `overflow: hidden;` to your `<ul>` is a fix for that.